# haml syntax issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

why this is not haml valid syntax

```
= form_tag(media_path(place_id: @place) , :multipart => true)  do
  = label_tag :image , "Place image"
  = file_field_tag :image
  = submit_tag "submit new comment"
```

Exception on line 46: compile error
    /.../show.html.haml:46: syntax error,             unexpected ':', expecting ')'
    ... form_tag(media_path(place_id: @place) , :multipart => true)...
                              ^
    Use --trace for backtrace.
    Use --trace for backtrace.

Comment: the error has nothing to do with haml. it's pure ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try :place_id => @place.id
Error may be also if you use @place instead @place.id

Answer (score 1):

first of all check the object of place and correct it to something like

`= form_tag(media_path(:place_id => @place) , :multipart => true)  do`

Refrence like code

`= form_tag(:url => media_path(:object_id =>@object),:html => {:class=> "form"} ) do`

Answer (score 1):

Actaully both didn't noticed that you are using ruby 1.9.2 hash syntax along with old 1.8.7 syntax style. I assume that you are trying to use this form with application running on 1.8.7, thats why it is giving you compile error. If you use ruby-1.9.2 you will not get that compile error. In ruby-1.9.2 you can declare you hash in Javascript json style. i.e {username: 'John'}

So either you use ruby-1.9.2 or change (place_id: @place) to (:place_id => @place)